# how to pass Parameters Info from the Body in ASP.NET Web APi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass a lengthy string through my POST methond from the actual body, it works perfectly fine if I pass it through url but I dont know what to change so I can insert data from body instead.

```
public void PostMethod(string id, [FromBody]string data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = client.Store(StoreMode.Add, id, data);
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
```

if I use it like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/api/data?id=2&data=MybigString
```

It works perfectly, but I don't want to pass data from URL, any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your action method, which is `public void PostMethod(string id, [FromBody]string data)`, you can use the URI of `http://localhost:8888/api/data/2` and the message body of `=MyBigString`. If you use jQuery, you can use something like this: `$.post('api/data/2', { '': 'MyBigString' });` to ensure the correct message body is sent.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: how would I use the JQuery to add some data?

Comment: How are you calling the web API now?

Comment: Im using Chrome Plug Ins , called POSTMAN, or SOAP UI

Comment: In POSTMAN, add a header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Select "raw" and enter `=MyBigString` in the textbox. For URL, use `http://localhost:8888/api/data/2`.

Comment: I just uploaded the screenshots, would you please take a look at it and tell me what Im doing wrong

Comment: Two things - Make sure URL is `http://localhost:port/api/logs/2`, assuming your controller is `LogsController`. Do not have `data` query string there. Also, I do not see the `Content-Type` header added with a value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. What you have in the "raw" textbox is correct. With this `id` parameter in the POST action method will be 2 and `data` will be "MyBigString".

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field and set the value of it before the post. Just make sure it's inside your form.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model.data)
```

To set the value in javascript using jQuery:

```
$("#data").val('my big string');
```

Alternatively, if you're not binding to a strongly-typed view, a simple HTML hidden input will work instead of the `@Html.HiddenFor()`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" />
```

Comment: would you please be little more specific, exactly where I need to modify, I'm programming in .net and if you are familiar with it, it does auto generates so many classes when you create a web api

Comment: I dont know... you tell me. Is that the View that's making the call to the API method?